# Geometry for Middle for schoolers (joining 5 points on a circle)

Tags: geometry, circles

If there are five points on a circle. How many line segments can be drawn on it, but without overlapping the regions?

Comment: what is a region?

Comment: Do you care to elaborate on the meaning of "regions"? You have connect the points in a pentagon like [this](http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/43400/43444/5c_43444_mth.gif), you can add more line segments, but they intersect like [this](http://www.opentutorial.com/images/thumb/3/32/5star-24-euclid.png/400px-5star-24-euclid.png). Finally, you can connect it all over the place like [this](http://www.zefdamen.nl/CropCircles/Reconstructions/2003/GreenStreet03/greenstreet10.gif). What do you have in mind?

Comment: You may mean that the line segments join pairs of vertices (the $5$ given points), and that two line segments can only meet at a vertex. Then drawing a few picturs should convince one of the answer, even if in Middle School a proof is difficult to write down.

Answer (score 1):

The number of line segments you can draw, each segment joining two of the 5 points on a circle, no two segments intersecting except at the 5 points, is 7. The five line segments that join the 5 points in a convex pentagon can certainly be drawn, since they don't intersect any other line segments (except at the 5 points). Having drawn those 5 line segments, you can draw any 2 diagonals of the pentagon, but no more than 2.

If that's not the question you want answered, please consider editing your question to clarify.